# Does a linker need to adjust segment size when relocation takes more space?

Tags: linker, static-linking

Let's assume the following:
There's a jump or a reference to data in an address reference encoded in 2 bytes. Now when statically linking, the relocation happens so that the new address does not fit in 2 bytes -- maybe it needs 4 bytes.

I assume the linker will rewrite the code, possibly using a different instruction, and use 4 bytes for the new address.

Does the linker then need to update the size of the current segment/section, and update all farther addresses by the same offset (+2 bytes in this example)?

Answer (score 0):

Machine instructions which refer to **external symbols** cannot use abbreviated form, where the displacement or immediate operand is encoded in one byte (extendable on runtime) instead of full word.

Linkers are not that smart to recompile the once assembled segments (at least the one that I wrote isn't :-)